# Is it OK to docker a tuleap for production environment

Tags: docker, tuleap

I wonder how if it's oK for using tuleap docker container as production site?
is it as safe and stable as full installtion? 
What's the best way to start it to make it more like a true server and easy to backup any change to host's volume?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: yes but not with `docker run -d enalean/tuleap-aio`

You can run it in production using docker but you should better be good at both Tuleap AND docker (esp. docker in production FWIW).

The default image (tuleap-aio) is rather designed for a test purpose and there is not volume management attached neither security upgrades.

If you want to do docker + tuleap in prod you will have to:

- be confident with docker in production itself
- be able to build your own tuleap image (with the list of plugin you want, your config & etc)
- be able to manage data volume for application and DB

Answer (score 0):

Docker is stable and safe; it's just a matter of figuring out how to use it.  You're going to want to look up the Compose File reference and set up the correct volumes, which requires an understanding of the application and its packaging in the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this Link

http://tracker.restlessdev.com/doc/en/developer-guide/quick-start/run-tuleap.html

This is the best way to have tuleap running in a docker container , the other way is just for testing without modify the source code of tuleap.